# Pseudoportable C script pattern

Tags: c, bash, portability, unix, compiler

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112123/pseudoportable-c-script-pattern-follow-up).)

From time to time, while working with a command line in *nix family of operating systems, we have to write those scripts doing a rather specific task. Usually we use `bash` + utility programs to do the job. However, I had to ask myself: how to implement such a script in C? After an invocation of such a script, it should perform the following:

1. Create a temporary source file \$S\$,
2. Dump the C code to \$S\$,
3. Compile \$S\$ to the program \$P\$,
4. Run \$P\$ passing the arguments to it and caching its exit status,
5. Remove \$S\$ and \$P\$,
6. Return the cached exit status of \$P\$.

**Code**

```
#! /bin/bash

# Below, XXXX asks for random characters in order to make a unique file name. 
# Mac OSX seems to ignore XXXX, yet Ubuntu requires them.

# Create a temporary file name for the source code:
TMP_SOURCE_FILE="$(mktemp -t sourceXXXX).c"
# Create a temporary file name for the executable file:
TMP_PROGRAM_FILE="$(mktemp -t programXXXX)"

# Write the source code into the temporary source file:
cat > $TMP_SOURCE_FILE <<- END_OF_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int i;

    puts("Hello, world! I am a pseudoportable C program.");
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) 
    {
        printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return argc - 1;
}
END_OF_SOURCE

# Compile and run:
gcc $TMP_SOURCE_FILE -o $TMP_PROGRAM_FILE
$TMP_PROGRAM_FILE $@
EXIT_STATUS=$?

# Clean the source and the binary:
rm $TMP_SOURCE_FILE
rm $TMP_PROGRAM_FILE

# Delegate the exit status of the C program to calling bash:
exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

So, what do you think? How can I improve anything? Also, can you come with an example of the situation where this "C script" pattern is more preferable than `bash` + command line utilities, Python, etc.?

Comment: Have you considered using [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) instead? It can run C as a script.

Comment: Never heard about tcc before. However, the aim is to be as "portable" as possible and it seems like I can't assume that the user has tcc installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not guaranteed that `$TMP_PROGRAM_FILE` is on the `$PATH`, so you need to either set the `$PATH` or use an absolute path for `$TMP_PROGRAM_FILE`.

You have problems with `mktemp`.

- **`-t` option:** It means different things on [GNU/Linux `mktemp(1)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html) and [Mac OS X `mktemp(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mktemp.1.html).

  On GNU/Linux:

  ```
  -t    interpret TEMPLATE as a single file name component,
        relative to a directory: $TMPDIR, if set; else the
        directory specified via -p; else /tmp [deprecated]
  ```

  On OS X:

  ```
  mktemp [-t prefix] template …
  mktemp -t prefix

      -t prefix
              Generate a template (using the supplied prefix and TMPDIR if set) to create a filename tem-plate. template.
              plate.
  ```

  Perhaps the confusion is the reason why the GNU/Linux man page indicates that it is deprecated.  I think you just want to run `mktemp TEMPLATE` without the `-t` option.
- **Cleanup:** Use `trap "rm $TMP_SOURCE_FILE $TMP_PROGRAM_FILE" EXIT` as a more robust way to delete the temporary files, in case your script aborts before reaching the `rm` commands.
- **`.c` suffix:**  By writing `TMP_SOURCE_FILE="$(mktemp -t sourceXXXX).c"`, you end up getting `mktemp` to create the file `sourceXXXX`.  That file does not get cleaned up.  Also, when you do `cat > $TMP_SOURCE_FILE`, you may be creating `sourceXXXX.c`, or worse, **truncating an existing file**.

  On GNU/Linux, a remedy would be to use the `--suffix .c` option.  Unfortunately, the BSD/OS X version doesn't support it.  One workaround is to rename the file after creation using `mv -i` — which might fail, but at least it's secure.

  A better workaround would be to use [`gcc -x c`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-x-77) to tell GCC that it is C source code, without considering the filename extension.

  An even better solution would be…
- **Avoid `$TMP_SOURCE_FILE` altogether:** `gcc` can take its source code from its standard input!  Use `-` as the filename.

  ```
  gcc -o "$TMP_PROGRAM_FILE" -x c - <<- END_OF_SOURCE
  …
  END_OF_SOURCE
  ```

Comment: For some reason I can't read the exit status of the embedded C program after the trap command. Tried on Ubuntu and OSX; both return systematically 0 when the number of arguments should be returned.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently, you need to [have the trap handler propagate the exit status explicitly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79654/17535).